# Wordpress: language_attributes for two languages?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Multiple Languages WordPress website
I want to change the language_attributes in each website.

Currently both English and french has

```
 <html lang="eng" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns" class=" ">
```

OR

change the language_attribute without changing the dashboard language

i want to change it, how can i do it ?

Comment: How are you handling multiple languages? Through a plugin? If so, which one? The approach you take will be based on your current setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your default lanuage is english from admin then below code would work to change your language in header html tag.

```
function change_locale($locale){
    //check if french website
    if(//french website){
        $locale = 'fr_FR';
    }
    else{
        $locale = 'en_US';
    }   
    return $locale;
}
add_filter('locale','change_locale',10);
```